# How to solve the problem "relative jump out of range"

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox

```
TITLE ASSIGNMENT MAIN MENU                                          ; title directive

.MODEL SMALL                                                        ; declare memory model used (small)
.STACK 64                                                           ; declare stack segment (64 bytes)
.DATA                                                               ; declare data segment

    ;main menu data
    HEADMENU    DB "   Main Menu$"
    OPT1        DB "1. View menu$"
    OPT2        DB "2. View Discount Rate$"
    OPT3        DB "3. Order$"
    OPT4        DB "4. Payment$"
    OPT5        DB "5. Summary$"
    OPT6        DB "Enter your selection > $"
    INVALIDMSG  DB "Invalid selection. Please try again.$"
    TEMP        DB '?'
    
    ;view disocunt data
    DISCT       DB "PURCHASE                DISCOUNT RATE$"  
    DISCT1      DB "================================================$"
    DISCT2      DB "Less Than RM 60                  NA  $"
    DISCT3      DB "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^$"
    DISCT4      DB "More Than Or Equal               10%     $"
    DISCT5      DB "RM 60                        $"
    DISCT6      DB "More Than Or Equal           15%     $"
    DISCT7      DB "RM 80                        $"

        ;view menu data
    ENDMENU DB  "Press any to exit >> ", '$'                                             
    HEADDIS DB  "    NAME          PRICE     |     NAME                PRICE$"
    ROW1    DB  " ==============================================================================$"
    DASH    DB  "                    |                       $"
    ROW2    DB  " 1. Berry Protein     18.00     | 10. Mango Magic             10.50     $"
    ROW3    DB  " 2. Mango Protein     17.00     | 11. Strawberry Squeeze      12.50     $"
    ROW4    DB  " 3. Peach Protein     18.00     | 12. Mango Lychee            10.50     $"
    ROW5    DB  " 4. 5-A Day Juice     16.50     | 13. Muesli Bar               5.90     $"
    ROW6    DB  " 5. Wild-B Juice      16.00     | 14. Banana Cake             14.50     $"
    ROW7    DB  " 6. Energise Juice         15.50     | 15. Chocolate Muffin       10.50     $"
    ROW8    DB  " 7. Apple Juice           15.50     | 16. Chocolate Ball           3.90     $"
    ROW9    DB  " 8. Orange Juice      14.50     | 17. Peanut Butter Ball       3.90     $"
    ROW10   DB  " 9. Peach Juice           12.00     | 18. Carrot Muffin            4.90     $"


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.CODE                                                               ; declare code segment

    MAIN PROC NEAR                                                  ; main procedure starts here

        MOV AX, @DATA                                               ; load the starting address of DATA segment into AX
        MOV DS, AX                                                  ; store the data inside the data register

        MainLoop:
            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, HEADMENU                                                ; load the effective address of HEAD (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, OPT1                                                ; load the effective address of OPT1 (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, OPT2                                                ; load the effective address of OPT2 (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, OPT3                                                ; load the effective address of OPT3 (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, OPT4                                                ; load the effective address of OPT4 (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, OPT5                                                ; load the effective address of OPT5 (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, OPT6                                                ; load the effective address of MSGEXIT (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation

            MOV AH, 01H                                                 ; accept a character that the user inputs
            INT 21H

        ; Valid selection, proceed to corresponding label
            CMP AL, '1'
            JE Option1Label
            CMP AL, '2'
            JE Option2Label
            CMP AL, '3'
            JMP Option3Label
            CMP AL, '4'
            JMP Option4Label
            CMP AL, '5'
            JMP Option5Label

            ; Display invalid selection message
        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H                                                 ; prepare to display the string
            LEA DX, INVALIDMSG                                          ; load the effective address of INVALIDMSG (variable) into DX register
            INT 21H                                                     ; carry out the operation
            JMP MainLoop                                                ; return to the main menu

        Option1Label:
            ; Code for Option 1 (Menu)
            ; Display details for Option 1

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH, 02H
        MOV DL, 0AH
        INT 21H                             ; move to the next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;display HEADDIS
    LEA DX , HEADDIS                
    INT 21H 
                
    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW1               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line
    
    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW2               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation
    
    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW3               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW4               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW5               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW6               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW7               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW8               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW9               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , DASH               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW10              ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ROW1               ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

    MOV AH , 09H                ;please prepare, I want to display the string (09H)
    LEA DX , ENDMENU                ;load the effective address MESSAGE(variable) into DX register
    INT 21H                 ;carry out the operation

    MOV AH, 01H                 ;read user input (selection)
    INT 21H

    MOV AH , 02H                
    MOV DL , 0AH                
    INT 21H                 ;next line

        JMP MainLoop             

        Option2Label:

    ; Display discount information

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT1
            INT 21H
      
        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H       

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT2
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT3
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line     

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT4
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT5
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H        

        MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT3
            INT 21H                                                 ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT6
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

            MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT7
            INT 21H

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H        

        MOV AH, 09H
            LEA DX, DISCT3
            INT 21H                                                 ; move to the next line

            JMP MainLoop                                                ; move to the next line
            ; Code for Option 2 (Order)
            ; Display details for Option 2

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line     

            ; Insert code for displaying order details here

            JMP MainLoop                                                ; return to the main menu

        Option3Label:
         ; Code for Option 2 (Order)
            ; Display details for Option 2

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line     

            ; Insert code for displaying order details here

            JMP MainLoop                                                ; return to the main menu

        Option4Label:
            ; Code for Option 4 (Payment)
            ; Display details for Option 4

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line     

            ; Insert code for displaying payment details here

            JMP MainLoop                                                ; return to the main menu   

    Option5Label:
            ; Code for Option 5 (Summary)
            ; Display details for Option 5

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line

        MOV AH, 02H
            MOV DL, 0AH
            INT 21H                                                     ; move to the next line     

            ; Insert code for displaying summary details here

            JMP MainLoop                                                ; return to the main menu                                                           
    
            ; Insert code for displaying summary details here

            JMP MainLoop                                                ; return to the main menu

    MAIN ENDP                                                       ; end of procedure

END MAIN                                                            ; end of the program
```

In the code above, the info ";view menu data" is successfully shown, however the ";view discount data" cant shown and prompt out an error "relative jump out of range" when I run it, it shows that "CMP AL, '2'
JE Option2Label"
this line got problem, how can I solve it?

I am expecting the output for ";view discount data" same as it will prompt out ";view menu data" when user input is '1'

Comment: If you tell the assembler it can use 386 instructions, `jcc rel16` is available with the same range as `jmp rel16`.

Answer (score 0):

If a short jump is to a location too far away, you can reverse the sense of the jump by changing:

```
        CMP AL, '2'
        JE Option2Label
```

into:

```
        CMP AL, '2'
        JNE NotOption2Label
        JMP Option2Label
NotOption2Label:
```

Alternatively, you could refactor your code so that it uses common subroutines to do some of the work, that's likely to allow you to reduce the sizes of those option subroutines somewhat :-)

The fact that your code consists of a lot of alternating `int21 fn09` calls to output a string and `int21 fn02` calls to output a newline could allow you to simply refactor each pair into a subroutine, That should, as a start provide a way to almost halve the size.

So something like:

```
LineNewLine:
        ;; DX should already be loaded before calling.
        MOV AH , 09H   ;; Output string in DX.
        INT 21H
        MOV AH , 02H   ;; Output new line.
        MOV DL , 0AH
        INT 21H
        RET
```

Then you can convert every pair as follows, making each smaller. I estimate from about eleven bytes *per pair* down to about six, but I haven't checked thoroughly (it's been a while since I've done any 8086 assembler). And the cost is just a single function of about nine bytes.

```
        MOV AH, 09H    -->   LEA  DX, DASH     2->3
        LEA DX, DASH         CALL LineNewLine  3->3
        INT 21H                                1->0

        MOV AH, 02H                            2->0
        MOV DL, 0AH                            2->0
        INT 21H                                1->0
```

---

As an aside, another thing you may want to look at is that your checks for options 3, 4, and 5, do not appear to be conditional:

```
        CMP AL, '3'
        JMP Option3Label  ; ???
        CMP AL, '4'
        JMP Option4Label  ; ???
        CMP AL, '5'
        JMP Option5Label  ; ???
```

That's probably why it doesn't complain about those ones but the result is the they will *all* execute option 3.

---

Another possibility: I can't remember whether you can encode control character into the `int21 fn09` stream but, if you can, you can probably combine quite a lot of that into a single call, something like (with `13, 10` being the codes for `CR/LF`):

```
MENU:   DB "   Main Menu", 13, 10
        DB "1. View menu", 13, 10
        DB "2. View Discount Rate", 13, 10
        DB "3. Order", 13, 10
        DB "4. Payment", 13, 10
        DB "5. Summary", 13, 10
        DB "Enter your selection > $"
        :
        MOV AH, 09H
        LEA DX, MENU
        INT 21H            ;; That's it, entire menu is output.
```

If control characters *are* allowed in the string, that will have a massive impact on the code size.

Comment: "I can't remember whether you can encode control character into the int21 fn09 stream" You can. However, linebreaks in DOS should use `13,10` to do a CR then LF.